# Table Filtering drop down list Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently doing my final year project and it make use of excel VBA whereby I am bad at it. I am really hope someone could guide me through the problem that I am facing.

As for now, I am hoping that I can use a drop down list to filter my table whereby it only shows the particular department and weeks I want to show.

From the image below,
From the range("C7:L26"), whenever I filter cell(F2) or cell(J2), it will leave the data that I want from the dropdown list.

For example, if cell(F2) = 2 and cell J2 = e,
From range("C7,L26"), it will only show department with value "e" and have week 2 in it. As for cells that does not have the department value or week value, it will be cleared or blank.

I also hope that if it is possible to press a button to return the table back to default.

Do guide me and I really need your help!! Thank You

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/SolTn.jpg
[2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXfUS.jpg

As for now I have this as my codes that I've learnt from a user @PeterT

```css
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:AW28")) Is Nothing Then
    
        Dim legendWS As Worksheet
        Dim legendcell As Range
        Set legendWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legend")
        
        Set legendcell = legendWS.Range("A2:A18").Find(Target.Value) 
        
        If Not legendcell Is Nothing Then
            Target.Interior.Color = legendcell.Interior.Color  
            
        End If
    End If

        

End Sub
```

End Sub

Comment: Record a macro and go from there. Your example code has nothing to do with your question. I'm guessing you don't want to learn VBA, despite it being part of your curriculum  ;)

Comment: I do have to learn it as I have to know what are the codes doing for each lines.

Comment: OK, so record a macro of you doing the filter and look at the code it creates then amend it. If you don't understand anything search online or post back here.

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! I will try it :D